# Qualitative study of a differential equation (with parameter)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this Cauchy problem
$$y'=\frac{y^\alpha}{(x^2+1)^\alpha},\ y(0)=1$$
I have to determine the values of $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that the solution has finite limit for $x\to\infty.$
The differential has the trivial solution $y(x)=0.$
Because of Cauchy Lipschitz, the solution and the first derivative are always positive, then we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{y'(x)}=0.$$ This is possible if and only if $\alpha\geq\frac{1}{2}.$ I know that the answer is $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}.$ The case $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ is easy to exclude, solving the differential, but how can I prove that the other values are solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By separating the variables, you have that, for $a\in (0,1)$, the solution is implicitly defined by the relation
$$
\frac{1}{1-a}[y^{1-a}-1] = \int_0^x \frac{1}{(t^2+1)^a}\, dt.
$$
Hence, the solution has a finite limit as $x\to +\infty$ if and only if the integral at the r.h.s. has a finite limit as $t\to +\infty$, i.e. if and only if 
$a > 1/2$.